# retrofit 2 and xml at android

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit

What class i have to create to receive one XML element?

i'm receiving XML from API:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">cat</string>
```

i've got class :

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class Translation {

    @Element(name = "string")
    private String string;

    public String getString(){
        return string;
    }
    public Translation() {

    }
}
```

and catching error:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=string, required=true, type=void) on field 'string' private java.lang.String com.antonioleiva.mvpexample.app.main.Utils.Network.Translation.Translation.string for class com.antonioleiva.mvpexample.app.main.Utils.Network.Translation.Translation at line 1
```

Comment: The Xml is from a SOAP service?

Comment: yes, from https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate

Comment: try using ksoap2 instead retrofit for soap

Answer (score 0):

if you are used to of retrofit then covert xml to json .

```
 public class Main {

public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><test attrib=\"moretest\">Turn this to JSON</test>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        System.out.println(je.toString());
    }
}
}
```

the output will be

```
{"test": {
    "attrib": "moretest",
    "content": "Turn this to JSON"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this [link](https://github.com/asanchezyu/RetrofitSoapSample). This sample project gives a clear indication of using SOAP with Retrofit